# Get record with two datetimes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have an issue where I'm trying to get an specific record where I have two dates to get an record.

The date are as follows:

```
StartTime: '2018-03-02 09:00:00.000'
EndTime : '2018-03-02 11:00:00.000'
```

The table looks like this:
[image]

From the dates above im trying to get the row number 5. 
I have tried it like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM [data].[EmergencyOrders]
WHERE [Workcenter] = @Workcenter
  AND [StartDatetime] > @StartTime
  AND ISNULL([EndDatetime], GETDATE()) < @StopTime
```

But can't seem to get it to work correctly.

Comment: The starttime condition isn't fulfilled.

Comment: You're not getting record 5 because start time is earlier than 9 o'clock.

Comment: The problem im having are that the record are before the time im getting. So some have i need to look where these two dates i have fit into.

Comment: I guess you mean 6th row? 5th row starttime is before your start condition

Comment: I mean with the start and end times shown above i should get the row where EmergencyOrderId are equal to 232.

Comment: You know 7am is before 9am ?

Comment: yes i know that. But maybee im not clear. From what i write above. Then the order startede at 07:19am and ended at 2:02PM. But im asking what are the order status in the time 09am and 11am. Which in this case are the row number 5

Comment: I understand now. But as you can imagine that logic explanation is much more clear than `im trying to get the row number 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know records containing both `StartTime` and `EndTime` then you do

```
WHERE @StartTime BETWEEN  [StartDatetime] AND ISNULL([EndDatetime], GETDATE())
  AND @EndTime BETWEEN  [StartDatetime] AND ISNULL([EndDatetime], GETDATE())
```

Now the problem I see is if you data range overlap with two ranges. In that case you will have two status. For that I suggest you calculate overlap ranges and select the last one.

[Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM [data].[EmergencyOrders]
WHERE [Workcenter] = @Workcenter
WHERE @StartTime <=  ISNULL([EndDatetime], GETDATE()) 
  AND @EndTime >=  [StartDatetime] 
ORDER BY EmergencyID DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to get those records which intersect with your date range which means you need something like the below SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM [data].[EmergencyOrders]
WHERE
    [Workcenter] = @Workcenter AND
    (([StartDatetime] BETWEEN @StartTime AND @StopTime) OR
     (ISNULL([EndDatetime], GETDATE()) BETWEEN @StartTime AND @StopTime)
```